# What is internal and external storage?

Tags: app2sd, storage

My phone said that the *Golf 2* app is moved to the SD card.

In the app info section I have the following choices:

- Force stop
- Uninstall
- Move to internal storage

Is internal storage the SD?

Answer (score 1):

Your phone's internal storage is not the SD card, it's the internal partition where all apps and app data goes to. There's an automatic decision to put excessive data somewhere else (the SD card) if an app is too big. Your app was already installed to the SD card and you therefore have an option to move it back to the *internal* storage.

There are mainly the following sections:

- /system - The firmware sits here. Write protected.
- /data - all apps and app data goes here.
- /mnt/sdcard - This is your external sdcard. Also referred to as **external storage**
- There are some other but the above 3 are the most important/interesting ones

If free space in the internal section (/data) is low, Android allows to move certain apps/data from /there to the SD card to free space.