# Where is Google Play Books storage location?

Tags: google-play-books

I found hints that the location might be "Android/data/com.google.android.apps.books". I don't have that folder. I have searched every file in my system looking for the book file.  I have folders: "...apps.magazines"   and "....apps.maps", but no "...apps.books".  Also what does the thumbtack mean on the books page cover under library view... Is there a manual somewhere?

Comment: This question has been asked before. You might want to take a look at [Where does Google Play store its ebooks on an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27007/16575)

Comment: I saw that comment that you refer to above but as I said I do not have the file Android/data/com.google.android.apps.books/files/volumes/ on my internal or external card.  Also I have a book that I can read off line, but where does it reside.. Galaxy 10.1 Tab

Comment: I'm leaving this question open, because @user37546 hasn't found a solution in Izzy's suggestion.