# Make Google Play Books store ebooks to external storage

Tags: external-sd, google-play-books

I have little internal storage of my Android device; How can I make Google Play Books store the ebooks to external storage?

I use Sony Xperia M (4.3 JB version).

Comment: Here is another post with a similar question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/where-does-google-play-store-its-ebooks-on-an-android-device It looks like you may need to root it.

Comment: @Freddie_V4 I dont want any rooting to do on my Newly buyed Sony Xperia M. It would void my warranty. Is any other way without rooting the device ?

Answer (score 1):

You must root your device and move the application to an external storage because the application stores the E-books in com.google.android. file. Unfortunately your application won't work if you move that folder without rooting.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 (Android 4.4.2) with Link2SD Plus, which requires a rooted device. Just press "Link to SD Card" and it should be able to move everything.

**Important:**
You need to set up your external storage with the appropriate partitions! [Here's](http://www.link2sd.info/description) how to do that.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: App status after linking]