# Store ePUB books on my external SD Card to be read in Google Play Books

Tags: storage, google-play-books, epub

This is a simple question, but in 2 parts:

1. I want my entire ePUB library stored *locally* on my Android device, so I can use Google Play Books to read them without the need of being connected to my cloud library or any other "online" storage.
2. Is it possible to configure Google Play Book to save/read the books library in the Android's external SD Card, *without* the need of storing them in the internal memory?

If you know the answer, or any tips about how to configure this scenario, it will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please don't tell me "You don't need that...", "e-books does not occupy space in internal memory...", "Why do you want all books stored locally?...".

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I won't tell you that – but if you want to own your own library on your own device, *Google Play Books* is the last thing to use. It's closed bottom up, and you're not supposed to use it with your own books (but only with books offered by Google). If you're open to open alternatives, check my app list for [eBook Readers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_ebookreaders). If you can live without DRM, *Moon+ Reader* would be my first choice (great support, many formats) – otherwise *Aldiko*.

Comment: I just tested it, it's technically possible doing this in Play Book, but... is it really worth the time & disk space? Note that you can upload your EPUB and then redownload it in Play Book. However, Google has its own format for downloaded eBooks (not EPUB, but more like the extracted content of it). Thus, you basically have 2 copies for each eBook, and Play Book doesn't use the EPUB stored on your storage anymore. As for your second question regarding saving, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/. I kind of agree that Play Book is probably not the best choice here...

Answer (score 1):

If they're non-DRM epub books, you could use a third party reader. Otherwise, it may depend on what version of Android you're running. Generally you're stuck with whatever options Google offers. With DRM (paid/protected) books you pretty much have to play by their rules as that's what stops people from say sharing books with those who haven't paid for them.